# cant search in google earth using c#?

Tags: c#, com, google-earth-plugin

I follow this tutorial

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31603/Embedding-Google-Earth-in-a-C-Application?fid=1532226&fr=26#xx0xx

to embed google in my windows form c# application.

This is the code i've used to search in google earth app:

```
try
{
    SearchControllerGE srch = new SearchControllerGE();
    srch.Search(textBox7.Text);  //textBox7.Text = "India"
    FeatureCollectionGE fcge = srch.GetResults();
}
catch(Exception eXZ)
{
    MessageBox.Show(eXZ.Message);
}
```

`srch.Search` throw an exception here is the exception message:

> error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Please if there is anybody have Previous experience about linking c# application with google earth by COM API Only without any Javascript API help me in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> linking c# application with google earth by COM API Only without any Javascript API.

[The COM api has been depreciated for years](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/sunset-for-google-earth-com-api.html).